# how does selecting input type=file work in jquery

Tags: jquery

i am following a tutorial on how to upload files with ajax and i came across this line of code.

```
var fileToUpload = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files[0];
// I change it to this. And now its undefined.
var fileToUpload = $('input[type="file"]').files[0];
```

I am really confused on how selecting input type file is difference from selecting input type text. And also is using `.val()` the same as using `[0].files[0]`?

Comment: `val()` on file input will only give you filename string

Answer (score 1):

Both are different, since the first one will be invoking `.file[0]` from plain `node object` whereas the second one is invoking `.file[0]` over a wrapper `jquery object`. Since the jquery object doesn't contains any property like files, the second one will throw error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…)`

At the same time `.val()` will return the `value` property of a node object and it can be invoked over jquery object not over plain node object.

If you want to check what are all the `enumerable properties` available with Jquery, then just execute the following in your console.

```
var x = $();
Object.keys(x.__proto__)
```

Answer (score 1):

> And also is using `.val()` the same as using `[0].files[0]`?

No. `.files` is a <strike>method</strike> property of [`input type="file"`](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/aria/input.file.html) element that returns a [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object . `.files` is not a jQuery method. `.val()` does not return `FileList` object.

To use jQuery to retrieve `FileList` you could utilize [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) with parameter `"files"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(":file").change(function() {
        console.log($(this).prop("files"))
      })
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.files is not a jQuery method.` Its not a method. Isn't it?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy You are correct, `.files` is a property of `input` element , not a method